# How to rewrite sub-folder with node express-urlrewrite?

Tags: node.js, express, url-rewriting

Using `express-urlrewrite`, I can't figure out how to rewrite a sub-folder to effectively 'remove' it.

**For example:**

`/en/` should become `/`

`/en/home` should become `/home`

**My attempt so far:**

```
app.use(rewrite(/^\/(en|es)\/[*]/, '/$1'));
```

How would I go about rewriting any en or es sub-folders?

Comment: [Character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[ ]` have special semantics. `[*]` matches a star, surely not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular regex, just test it outside of `app.use`.

The task is *"remove `/en` or `/es` from the start of the string"*.

So let's write a regex that matches `/en` or `/es` at the start of the string. To avoid false positives (like `/energy`), let's make sure the following character, if any, is either a `/` or a `?`:

```
"/en/home/bla".replace(/^\/(en|es)(?=[/?]|$)?/, '')
```

results in `/home/bla`.

```
app.use(rewrite(/^\/(en|es)(?=[/?]|$)?/, ''));
```

Regex breakdown (I've removed the regex-literal-specific escaping):

```
^                # start of string
/                # a forward slash
(                # group 1
  en|es          #   "en" or "es"
)                # end group 1
(?=              # look-ahead
  [/?]           #   one of forward slash, question mark
  |              #   or
  $              #   end of string
)                # end look-ahead
```